# Connection to Compute Engine with No External IP Possible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iap

I am not sure if is a strange behavior of Google Compute Engine. I have a VM without External IP.
Now, where I click the ssh button I can still connect to it and I see the log:

> External IP address was not found; defaulting to using IAP tunneling.

I have not configured any IAP though. So how can that be possible? Is then IAP tunnelling always on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity Aware Proxy is a managed Google Cloud service. This service is always running. Access is controlled through IAM roles. The CLI is connecting to an IAP endpoint, requesting the creation of a TCP tunnel and then forwarding traffic to your instance via this tunnel.

Comment: Reading here ... https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding ... it seems to pose (for me) two follow on questions:

1. Do I have to open up ingress for IAP's  netblock 35.235.240.0/20
2. Does the SSH session starter have to have the "IAP-Secured Tunnel User" role?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set an external IP address to your VM Instance as you can see on [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances), you will have to set any of this 3 methods to connect to your Instance: 1.- [Creating a VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#vpn), 2.- [Using a Bastion Host](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#bastion_host), 3.- Using [Identity and Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#cloud_iap)

The must common is to use IAP or VPN, Bastion host method is more complicated and expensive.

Comment: Ok but I understand that while the other methods require a set up, the IAP is "always" on, it is just a matter to add users to the proper IAM role, right? thanks.

Comment: As the accepted answer said, IAP is some default feature of GCP security. It adapts the forwarding traffic as an HTTPS stream, combined with OAuth to certificate the users / applications you want to get access to your project / VM Instances.